# Rotate wheel and stop at specific point in EaselJs

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I am new to EaselJs.
I am rotating a wheel with 9x numbers and 3 (0x), the total of 12 numbers. I am able to rotate the wheel by calling function, but I want to stop it on predefined specific point/number of the wheel.

```
var _oContainer;

this._init = function(iXPos,iYPos){
    _oWheel = s_oSpriteLibrary.getSprite("wheel_circle");
    _oContainer = new createjs.Container;
    _oContainer.x = CANVAS_WIDTH - 200;
    _oContainer.y = CANVAS_HEIGHT - 350;
    s_oStage.addChild(_oContainer);
    img = createBitmap(_oWheel);
    img.regX = _oWheel.width / 2;
    img.regY = _oWheel.height / 2;
    _oContainer.addChild(img);
}

this.spin = function(b, a){
    //var h = new createjs.Bitmap(s_oSpriteLibrary.getSprite('wheel_circle'));
    createjs.Tween.get(_oContainer).to({
        rotation: _oContainer.rotation + a
    }, 2600, createjs.Ease.quartOut).call(function() {
        _oContainer.rotation %= 360;
    })
}
```

I am calling the spin function as `this.spin(5, 1131.7511808994204);` on every time button is clicked.

Right now it is spinning and stopping randomly on every button click. How can stop it on a specific number/position on the wheel?

What value should I give in `rotation:`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of factors in play to do something like this. I made a quick demo to show how I would do it:

1. Draw the wheel (at center) with segments. It is important to know how many segments you have so you can choose a place to "end"
2. Start spinning. Just increment the rotation each tick depending on how fast you want it to go.
3. When "stopping", you have to do math to determine where to land
4. To get a realistic "slow down", make sure the remaining rotation in the tween is enough so it doesn't speed up or slow down too rapidly

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ych1qt8u/1/

```
// Choose an end number. In this case, its just a number between 0 and the number of segments.
var num = Math.random() * segments | 0,

    // How many degrees is one segment? 
    // In my demo I use radians for `angle`, so I have to convert to degrees
    angleR = angle * 180/Math.PI,

    // Take the current rotation, add 360 to it to take it a bit further
    // Note that my demo rotates backwards, so I subtract instead of add.
    adjusted = c.rotation - 360,

    // Determine how many rotations the wheel has already gone since it might spin for a while
    // Then add the new angle to it (num*angleR)
    // Then add a half-segment to center it.
    numRotations = Math.ceil(adjusted/360)*360 - num*angleR - angleR/2;
```

Then I just run a tween to the new position. You can play with the duration and ease to get something you like.

```
createjs.Tween.get(c)
    .to({rotation:numRotations}, 3000, createjs.Ease.cubicOut);
```

Technically, I should change the duration depending on the actual remaining spin, since depending on the result, it might not be super smooth. This came close enough, so I left it as-is.

Hope that helps! Let me know if I can clarify anything further.

Comment: *(Just to point the obvious)* Sadly, the example does exactly what you tried to avoid, and that's: it does not catch up naturally the current angular velocity to then lerp / interpolate that ongoing animation with the synthetic one. So it looks pretty *rigged* at times. Even more the way that the needle ends up always in the sector's arc center.